# Finding out calling process for content provider (acore) process on API level 18

Tags: android, android-contentprovider

**Background :**

I want to find out who starts the `acore` process after I stop it and call clear data on the process.

**Log:**

> Sep 12 18:50:08 localhost 172.16.4.165 ANDROID: +05:30 2015 000 0 |
>   09-12 18:49:48.630 I/ActivityManager( 3304): Start proc
>   android.process.acore for content provider
>   com.android.providers.contacts/.ContactsProvider2: pid=4805 uid=10022
>   gids={50022, 1028}

There was nothing else in the log which could point me to what started the process. The `acore` process has other providers too but the above log narrows it down to the `ContactsProvider2`

**Issue :**

The process starts while the cleanup is still ongoing and this results in database getting corrupt.

**What I have already tried out :**

1. [How to find out a calling activity for content provider in Android?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25433956/how-to-find-out-a-calling-activity-for-content-provider-in-android)
   This has solution for API level 19 and above. But my device has API level 18
2. I tried out `Binder.getCallingPid()` in `onCreate()` this returns self PID
3. The `getCallingPid()` and `getCallingUid()` method which I normally use directly inside a "Service" are not available for "ContentProvider"

Comment: where do you call `Binder#getCallingPid` ?

Comment: I added it in onCreate()

Comment: when android.os.Process.myPid() == Binder.getCallingPid() it means that your own app calls the ContentProvider, **note**: this check can only be called in "transactional" methods like `query`, `update`, etc, `onCreate` is not such method

Comment: What would you suggest to use in onCreate() or any other place to find out who started the process.

Comment: what do you mean? just `Log.d` the value of `Binder.getCallingPid()` in `onCreate()` and in `query` method

Comment: The `Binder.getCallingPid()` works correctly in the `query()` method. I guess I will add the same on all the "transnational" methods and assume that the process was started by the same process. I guess that would be a fair assumption.

Comment: you cannot do this check in `ContentProvider#onCreate`, in that method `Binder.getCallingPid()` will always return self pid

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally this is what I did for those that are interested. For API level below 19 I could not find any way without modifying framework.

Below is my patch to ActivityManagerService.java which helped me.

```
diff --git a/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java b/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java
index 0081dfc..8ec15c3 100644
--- a/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java
+++ b/services/java/com/android/server/am/ActivityManagerService.java
@@ -6676,6 +6676,9 @@ public final class ActivityManagerService  extends ActivityManagerNative
                             Slog.w(TAG, "Failed trying to unstop package "
                                     + cpr.appInfo.packageName + ": " + e);
                         }
+                       Slog.w(v, "startProcessLocked for cpi.processName = "+cpi.processName
+                           +"::cpi.applicationInfo.packageName=" + cpi.applicationInfo.packageName
+                            + " (Binder.getCallingPid()=" + Binder.getCallingPid());

                         ProcessRecord proc = startProcessLocked(cpi.processName,
                                 cpr.appInfo, false, 0, "content provider",
@@ -6692,6 +6695,7 @@ public final class ActivityManagerService  extends ActivityManagerNative
                         mLaunchingProviders.add(cpr);
                     } finally {
                         Binder.restoreCallingIdentity(origId);
+                        Slog.w(TAG, "Binder.getCallingPid() after restoreCallingIdentity(). pid=" + Binder.getCallingPid());
                     }
                 }
```